# Converting an array of text to vectors

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow

I am currently working on a sentiment analysis project using `tensorflow` and `tflearn`. I have a dataset of social media posts that were given to me in a CSV file and I'm trying to turn them into a vector to use for training.

This is my first attempt at doing something like this manually, I've usually import datasets that were preprocessed already.

Currently, here is the code I've tried from the resources I've found during a google search:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy 
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn
from tflearn.data_utils import to_categorical, pad_sequences
from tflearn.datasets import imdb
import keras
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pickle
import csv

highschool_posts = pd.read_csv('Depression-Posts-Sentiment.xlsx-Sheet1.csv',names=["Post"],header=None,skiprows = 1)
highschool_posts
# with open()
# pickle.dump(highschool_posts,'highschool_posts.pkl')
posts = pd.DataFrame.as_matrix(highschool_posts)
print(posts.shape)
print(posts[0:2])
# print(posts)

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input = highschool_posts,
                            analyzer = "word",
                            tokenizer = None,
                            preprocessor = None,
                            stop_words = None,
                             max_features =5000)
print(vectorizer)
```

When I print the results I get this:

```
(14, 1)
[[ "You'd think i'd feel the worst when im alone but it gets worst when im around you"]
 [ 'I took too many drugs and I passed out and started foaming at the mouth. I wish that it would have killed me but it did not. Ugh ']]
CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8',
        input=                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ...hill day at school today! Wonderful day... one...  WOW WE GRADUATED TODAY FINALLY!! This isn't th...,
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=5000, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
        tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)
```

Would anyone have better insight as to what I could try to get an output that looks something like this? :

```
([[17, 25, 10, 406, 26, 14, 56, 61, 62, 323, 4],
  [17,
   10,
   2,
   6409,
   25,
   325,
   7,
   3161,
   4,
   2588,
   1977,
   176,
   3,
   26,
   50,
   35,
   70,
   1050,
   395,
   4],
  [9846,
   8681,
   56,
   33,
   80,
   113,
   125,
   62,
   116,
   4397,
   5,
   17,
   10,
   70,
   284,
   4,
   277,
   2480,
   23,
   92,
   46,
   49,
   4358,
   1,
   31,
   78,
   116,
   4],
  [824,
   69,
   704,
   47,
   389,
   8,
   1373,
   4,
   100,
   365,
   1268,
   8,
   17,
   3524,
   27,
   4,
   573,
   2433,
   299,
   192,
   418,
   194,
   174,
   536,
   120,
   8,
   364,
   4],
  [39,
   7,
   69,
   519,
   154,
   10,
   42,
   2,
   468,
   65,
   5518,
   31,
   6,
   1924,
   1,
   1181,
   8,
   210,
   45,
   1,
   4942,
   87,
   15,
   78,
   6544,
   40,
   259,
   1,
   388,
   23,
   9420,
   40],
  [16,
   117,
   14,
   20,
   39,
   7,
   2,
   829,
   116,
   74,
   35,
   140,
   107,
   3,
   5,
   16,
   155,
   126,
   125,
   86,
   2,
   286,
   10,
   142,
   3,
   26,
   14,
   20,
   145,
   6,
   67,
   62,
   25,
   40],
  [16,
   21,
   585,
   1656,
   44,
   2,
   4640,
   3111,
   5,
   5022,
   7,
   2996,
   1,
   3,
   15,
   17,
   1291,
   1025,
   3,
   8772,
   5,
   2002,
   1433,
   27,
   4,
   1292,
   30,
   48,
   88,
   3,
   1,
   3268,
   1,
   7315,
   4],
  [9435,
   2605,
   20,
   251,
   10,
   59,
   1388,
   58,
   15,
   69,
   358,
   164,
   17,
   27,
   4,
   66,
   1,
   58,
   2,
   7886,
   1168,
   7,
   2,
   27,
   24,
   45,
   1,
   1697,
   4,
   16,
   71,
   49,
   8,
   79,
   64,
   7,
   52,
   4],
  [16,
   133,
   41,
   36,
   179,
   26,
   17,
   282,
   49,
   176,
   403,
   801,
   403,
   17,
   282,
   64,
   49,
   6,
   19,
   604,
   1880,
   1,
   19,
   4,
   16,
   117,
   92,
   49,
   14,
   75,
   99,
   19,
   14,
   20,
   47,
   604,
   1880,
   19,
   4],
  [17,
   25,
   935,
   1270,
   1,
   1120,
   15,
   6,
   3538,
   1328,
   4,
   723,
   18,
   3,
   14,
   935,
   6,
   378,
   96,
   242,
   24,
   760,
   3,
   2231,
   431,
   4,
   18,
   14,
   204,
   22,
   125,
   1115,
   6119,
   3151,
   61,
   92,
   213,
   38,
   7467,
   4],
  [17,
   56,
   45,
   236,
   3,
   3016,
   651,
   1,
   1038,
   131,
   3,
   26,
   14,
   20,
   1050,
   24,
   351,
   474,
   5,
   1,
   330,
   323,
   4,
   1,
   3374,
   6889,
   10,
   2282,
   3,
   480,
   2,
   588,
   7,
   6,
   865,
   76,
   5,
   474,
   4419,
   24,
   52,
   687,
   4],
  [6,
   1525,
   7,
   5172,
   544,
   1901,
   24,
   6,
   1,
   1611,
   771,
   4,
   2,
   952,
   10,
   960,
   397,
   5,
   371,
   3,
   127,
   54,
   2,
   889,
   23,
   2146,
   1112,
   3304,
   4,
   16,
   63,
   32,
   278,
   17,
   21,
   644,
   15,
   2208,
   4,
   1,
   17,
   25,
   4],
  [5,
   16,
   77,
   399,
   18,
   4,
   16,
   1052,
   14,
   247,
   328,
   31,
   1,
   3,
   5,
   16,
   21,
   33,
   1006,
   14,
   8,
   38,
   48,
   62,
   4,
   17,
   10,
   167,
   39,
   7,
   69,
   2628,
   4,
   16,
   237,
   761,
   18,
   14,
   56,
   6,
   460,
   810,
   4],
  [17,
   27,
   1,
   5,
   1,
   42,
   6,
   414,
   25,
   749,
   15,
   522,
   3,
   5,
   2,
   1,
   6344,
   204,
   83,
   8,
   79,
   14,
   4,
   6,
   230,
   55,
   6418,
   92,
   87,
   2,
   869,
   571,
   933,
   772,
   7,
   92,
   260,
   47,
   6,
   180,
   5,
   9536,
   27,
   4],
  [101,
   39,
   21,
   88,
   142,
   3,
   16,
   80,
   515,
   14,
   6,
   189,
   4,
   17,
   39,
   56,
   33,
   68,
   1136,
   6,
   1801,
   4,
   2,
   336,
   21,
   791,
   102,
   966,
   206,
   63,
   425,
   257,
   804,
   3,
   26,
   15,
   2933,
   8,
   2,
   118,
   33,
   2,
   8998,
   4],
  [1,
   1921,
   4,
   17,
   56,
   8,
   38,
   39,
   7,
   2,
   262,
   116,
   16,
   37,
   140,
   126,
   4,
   2,
   431,
   10,
   7991,
   3,
   2,
   209,
   323,
   35,
   1307,
   4,
   2,
   75,
   169,
   18,
   824,
   83,
   164,
   21,
   2,
   1,
   5,
   494,
   2159,
   489,
   1,
   4],
  [49,
   174,
   2115,
   315,
   3,
   17,
   25,
   10,
   33,
   6,
   1410,
   2602,
   3,
   26,
   14,
   2009,
   24,
   2460,
   6057,
   4,
   6,
   67,
   67,
   8404,
   25,
   18,
   139,
   33,
   1,
   23,
   6,
   564,
   4,
   61,
   67,
   62,
   129,
   5,
   61,
   398,
   5874,
   22,
   89,
   4],
  [1212,
   89,
   107,
   130,
   25,
   4,
   370,
   15,
   1965,
   42,
   55,
   1147,
   246,
   4,
   23,
   6,
   503,
   446,
   25,
   3,
   67,
   89,
   107,
   4,
   131,
   10,
   615,
   8,
   8263,
   4,
   195,
   10,
   333,
   277,
   2730,
   1165,
   1,
   22,
   2,
   1000,
   24,
   1,
   20,
   6906,
   4],
  [6,
   180,
   230,
   47,
   468,
   8,
   147,
   40,
   50,
   35,
   464,
   654,
   154,
   26,
   14,
   20,
   95,
   4849,
   24,
   125,
   1298,
   1700,
   395,
   74,
   10,
   59,
   107,
   2,
   25,
   23,
   83,
   4,
   1521,
   76,
   381,
   24,
   6,
   67,
   1037,
   195,
   4,
   16,
   1539,
   515,
   14,
   40],
  [17,
   25,
   10,
   48,
   96,
   3,
   14,
   63,
   75,
   38,
   1080,
   8,
   2,
   3932,
   262,
   19,
   230,
   19,
   84,
   572,
   1779,
   833,
   4,
   70,
   928,
   482,
   2,
   25,
   4,
   98,
   159,
   2618,
   3,
   245,
   77,
   4,
   54,
   104,
   32,
   456,
   143,
   73,
   31,
   17,
   1246,
   4],
  [17,
   10,
   39,
   7,
   2,
   262,
   116,
   16,
   37,
   140,
   126,
   40,
   16,
   232,
   14,
   42,
   2,
   5829,
   27,
   1392,
   5,
   494,
   2562,
   3091,
   69,
   73,
   4,
   349,
   4014,
   24,
   70,
   1640,
   2397,
   1678,
   4,
   12,
   13,
   9,
   11,
   12,
   13,
   9,
   11,
   6964,
   793,
   4],
  [489,
   10,
   625,
   4,
   17,
   27,
   1343,
   61,
   7,
   2,
   134,
   544,
   1848,
   56,
   140,
   243,
   4,
   3685,
   1646,
   10,
   1048,
   1256,
   4,
   2,
   3177,
   35,
   398,
   3,
   26,
   22,
   223,
   3,
   2,
   306,
   1486,
   10,
   9125,
   324,
   4,
   34,
   10,
   2,
   134,
   3,
   964,
   206,
   4],
  [436,
   2826,
   193,
   1,
   67,
   88,
   4,
   129,
   21,
   67,
   62,
   4,
   76,
   80,
   6,
   957,
   5,
   236,
   1,
   4,
   2,
   3784,
   7,
   578,
   5,
   4526,
   410,
   21,
   2382,
   4,
   118,
   82,
   67,
   1088,
   5,
   430,
   49,
   30,
   109,
   401,
   78,
   1403,
   4,
   67,
   746,
   25,
   4],
  [6,
   1048,
   653,
   1,
   27,
   4,
   6449,
   3,
   322,
   5,
   492,
   101,
   27,
   7,
   2,
   172,
   4,
   4357,
   4921,
   31,
   2,
   1,
   3480,
   4,
   61,
   92,
   56,
   1080,
   2,
   1,
   7,
   2,
   27,
   24,
   1,
   20,
   122,
   86,
   89,
   3,
   18,
   1588,
   32,
   38,
   6,
   459,
   86],
  [1204,
   23,
   127,
   366,
   15,
   2,
   1244,
   7,
   106,
   956,
   428,
   5,
   406,
   129,
   3,
   17,
   27,
   158,
   128,
   38,
   309,
   896,
   30,
   35,
   307,
   23,
   6,
   62,
   4301,
   23,
   143,
   6790,
   4,
   16,
   63,
   32,
   838,
   266,
   178,
   546,
   17,
   21,
   6,
   19,
   62,
   25,
   4,
   19]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get this code from? It's not usual to use the `input` parameter. The `vectorizer` here is the object which does the vectorizing, not the vectorized text itself.  The usual scikit-learn idiom is to use the `fit` and `transform` (or `fit_transform`) methods:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(highschool_posts)
vectorized_text = vectorizer.transform(highschool_posts)
```

Take a look at the official tutorial http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html for a more comprehensive introduction.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually got the code from another SO thread and from reading the documentation. From what I saw, I thought that was the way I had to do it. This way makes more sense though. Although, the output seems to be `(0 , 0 )   1` even though there should be data available.

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial link i've added too